# C++ code crashes in Win 2000 but does not crash in Win xp

Tags: c++, windows-xp

```
main()
{       
int *p;

free(p);
}
```

This code crashes in Win 2K. But somehow does not crash in Win Xp! Any idea why?

Edit:  Yes. This is a bug and should not be written. 
Some more info: The compiler used was VC 6 compiler. Compiled the code in release mode on a Win Xp machine. Ran the executable with this code on multiple machines having Win Xp. The code did not result in any crash. But ran the same code on multiple Win 2K machines. It crashed every single time!!

Comment: You're playing Russian Roulette here. You never know when the next shot will have a real bullet.

Comment: Surely this is not the complete code!? http://sscce.org/

Comment: I know its a bug. What I would like to know is how different is Win Xp from Win 2k in terms of heap & stack management and stuff like that. I would have been happy if it were the other way round - crashing on Win Xp and not on Win 2K.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is Undefined Behavior. It may crash, may not crash, or even draw unicorn on display, there is no rules on how Undefined Behavior behaves.

Comment: There is a similar code on one the products I work on. It has never crashed on Win Xp machines. But the same code crashes every time on Win 2K! This is what I'm interested in! :)

Comment: @Alerter just initialize it with NULL and everything will be fine.

Comment: @Alerter. It's probably fluke... the pointer is allocated as either a register or on the stack. The compiler is under no obligation to zero out the pointer for you when it creates it... so it's created, but until you specifically initialize it with a value or NULL, it can point anywhere. So if it doesn't crash it means a) You were lucky and the pointer contents happened to be NULL, b) You were lucky, the intial pointer value pointed to an area of memory that you were allowed to "free", which incidently might cause other problems elsewhere in you rprogram

Comment: I don't think so it's a fluke. It fails every time in all Win 2K machines and it works fine in all Win Xp machines that I've tested.

Note: I've tested the code on at least 6 to 7 Win 2K and Win Xp machines

Comment: @Alerter: Is there any code between the pointer decl and the free() or have you boiled it down to that minimal test case? I still think it is a fluke :) if the pointer is left uninitialised to could be pointing anywhere. Try adding a print out of the pointer before you free it. On some machines you might see it as 0 and on the ones where it crashes, something else. Or at least you'll see different addresses...

Comment: Jimbo, its not a fluke. Use the above code and compile using vc6 compiler in release mode. Run it on Win Xp. It will not crash. Run it on Win 2K. It crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is Undefined Behaviour: you are trying to use (actually, free) an uninitialized pointer.

Since this is UB, it is totally irrelevant to try and understand why it works (or rather appears to) on one OS but not on the other: the principle of UB is "*all bets are off, anything could happen*".

Answer (score 0):

Is that exactly the code as it stands? I.e., nothing in between that initialises p?

As a guess I would say that on your XP system the compiler is initialising p to NULL (I don't think it has to, it just is). On the 2K system the compiler is just adding *p to the stack and the value could be anything.

Free(p) will correctly deal with NULL pointers but if your 2K system hasn't zeroed the pointer when it is created on the stack (which I don't think the C standard requires), then it could be dnagling, and hence free(p) might try to free some arbitrary memory, causing you the problem.

If you start with

```
int *p = NULL;
free(p);
```

does this change the behaviour?